# Why doesn't the $GLOBALS superglobal has an underscore?

Tags: php, superglobals

Just for curiosity. All superglobals (for example `$_POST`, `$_GET`, `$_FILES`, `$_SESSION`) have an underscore and only the `$GLOBALS` superglobal does not. Why is that so? What does the underscore mean in superglobal variables in PHP and generaly in PHP? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a good question, but it's probably for the same reason that PHP has so many other quirky features, like the ability to parse `$foo = bar;` with nothing more than a Notice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I saw a note on PHP manual page that says

> Note: Variable availability Unlike all of the other superglobals,
>   **$GLOBALS has essentially always been available in PHP**.

May be that's why they want to keep it like this, but this is just a guess.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php

Answer (score 2):

Previously, `$_POST` was referred to as `$HTTP_POST_VARS`, and other superglobals were similarly named.

It's entirely likely that `$_POST` was chosen because the practice of writing `$POST = &$HTTP_POST_VARS;` was significantly high back in PHP 4, so the underscore is there to prevent breaking that old code.

Of course, this is just a guess!

Comment: Interesting guess, I haven't really thought about that. If you have any sources that would be amazing, for now I will upvote. ;)